# Kubernetes Controller-Runtime: Manager cache to watch Annotation

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I am trying to set up a manager with Cache that cares about annotations. Here’s what I have so far

```golang
mgr, err := ctrl.NewManager(centralClusterCfg, ctrl.Options{
        Scheme:                 scheme,
        MetricsBindAddress:     metricsAddr,
        Port:                   9443,
        HealthProbeBindAddress: probeAddr,
        LeaderElection:         enableLeaderElection,
        LeaderElectionID:       "14153762.my.domain",
        NewCache: func(config *rest.Config, cacheOpts cache.Options) (cache.Cache, error) {
            cacheOpts.SelectorsByObject = cache.SelectorsByObject{
                &corev1.Secret{}: cache.ObjectSelector{
                    Field: fields.SelectorFromSet(fields.Set{
                        "metadata.annotations.myAnnotation": "useme",
                    }),
                },
            }
            return cache.New(config, cacheOpts)
        },
    })
```

and in `SetupWithManager`:

```golang
if err := mgr.GetFieldIndexer().IndexField(context.Background(), &corev1.Secret{}, "metadata.annotations.myAnnotation", func(rawObj client.Object) []string {
        secret := rawObj.(*corev1.Secret)
        if secret == nil {
            return nil
        }
        return []string{secret.Annotations["myAnnotation"]}
    }); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

But my controller returns:
`pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: field label not supported: metadata.annotations.myAnnotation`

Any tip what I am missing?

EDIT: It seems that it is not supported, at least according to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/bc98f7a5f2086a62af80ad92f7201e7af5e0ef03/pkg/apis/core/v1/conversion.go#L157

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but have you, by any chance, found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes does not support fieldSelector using annotations as you see in the link https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/bc98f7a5f2086a62af80ad92f7201e7af5e0ef03/pkg/apis/core/v1/conversion.go#L591-L602

So, unfortunately, you need to use `metadata.labels` for it or find another way